# How can I fix the [distance myself] to work properly in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want an agent breed mate to move towards a ball by itself. But this does not seem to be working. I think this may have to be with the label myself not being applicable to the breed but I am unsure.

```
breed[ ball balls]
breed[ mate team]

to move_mate
  ask mate[
    let nearest-ball min-one-of balls [distance myself]

    ; Move towards the nearest ball
    if nearest-ball != nobody [
      face nearest-ball
      fd 1 ; You can adjust the distance as needed
  ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you problem is just due wrong definition of your breeds. When defining a breed, you first name the plural (balls/team) and second the singular (ball/mate) (see [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breed)). NetLogo thinks you are asking for the singular which is not possible in your case. So either you have to use `let nearest-ball min-one-of ball [distance myself]` or you redefine your breed `breed[balls ball]`